# Owncloud install on localhost using XAMPP but cloud not working

Tags: xampp, cloud, owncloud

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQRPm.jpg)

Owncloud install on localhost `Xampp` htdocs file. but right now it showing `ownCloud Server does not support Microsoft Windows.`

Now am a lite bit confuse what should I do!?

Answer (score 0):

But Owncloud is very clear about that:

Server

Operating System    Ubuntu 16.04, Debian 7 and 8, SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 and 12 SP1, Red Hat Enterprise Linux/Centos 6.5 and 7
Database    MySQL or MariaDB 5.5+, Oracle 11g, PostgreSQL, & SQLite
Web server  Apache 2.4 with prefork Multi-Processing Module (MPM) and mod_php
PHP Runtime PHP (5.6+, 7.0, & 7.1)

Look: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.0/admin_manual/installation/system_requirements.html